# Getting unexpected date from DateTime class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to merge the strings of date and time to DateTime format so that I can have the difference of the two timestamps.

But when passing the date as "31-July-2019" and time as "5:07PM" (in proper format as you can see in the toDateTimeFormat method) to the DateTime constructor it gives me the unexpected date i.e 2019-07-01 17:07:00.000 where the expected date should be 2019-07-31 17:07:00.000

I have also tried using the DateTime.utc constructor but didn't succeed, below is my code

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main(){

  String dateOne = "31-July-2019";
  String timeOne = "5:07PM";

  String dateTwo = "01-Aug-2019";
  String timeTwo = "12:00AM";

  DateTime reminderDate = toDateTimeFormat(dateOne,timeOne);
  // 2019-07-01 17:07:00.000  which is wrong...,  EXPECTED --> 2019-07-31 17:07:00.000

  DateTime dueDate = toDateTimeFormat(dateTwo, timeTwo);

  bool value = isValidReminderDate(reminderDate, dueDate);
  // REMINDER DATE < DUE DATE SO RETURN TRUE ELSE FALSE...., EXPECTED --> TRUE
  print(value);
}

var monthsNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

DateTime toDateTimeFormat(String date, String time){
  if(date != null && time != null){
    //date: 01-jan-2000 and time: "6:45PM"

    List<String> _parts = date.split("-");
    List<String> _timeParts =[];

      var dt = DateFormat("h:mma").parse(time);
      _timeParts = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dt).split(":");

    DateTime dateTime =  DateTime(int.parse(_parts[2]),monthsNames.indexOf(_parts[1]),int.parse(_parts[0]), int.parse(_timeParts[0]), int.parse(_timeParts[1]) ,);

    // ALSO TRIED WITH DateTime.utc(int.parse(_parts[2]),monthsNames.indexOf(_parts[1]),int.parse(_parts[0]), int.parse(_timeParts[0]), int.parse(_timeParts[1]) ,);
    // but of no use...

    print("dateTime :: $dateTime");
    return dateTime;
  }
}

bool isValidReminderDate(DateTime reminderDate, DateTime dueDate){
  print('isValidReminderDate :: ${reminderDate.difference(dueDate).isNegative}');
  return reminderDate.difference(dueDate).isNegative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to parse these strings directly using `package:intl` (with one caveat below).

```
  var dateOne = "31-Jul-2019";
  var timeOne = "5:07PM";

  var dateTwo = "01-Aug-2019";
  var timeTwo = "12:00AM";

  var format = DateFormat("dd'-'MMM'-'yyyy hh:mma");
  var one = format.parse('$dateOne $timeOne');
  var two = format.parse('$dateTwo $timeTwo');

  print('$one $two ${two.difference(one)}');
```

prints `2019-07-31 17:07:00.000 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000 6:53:00.000000`

The caveat is that you must use `Jul` not `July` and `Sep` not `Sept` since you are using the 3 letter abbreviation elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, from this 2019-07-31 17:07:00.000 i want to exclude .000 part. i.e i want only 2019-07-31 17:07:00 this part. How should I do this?

Comment: That's the milliseconds being formatted by the naive `toString` of `DateTime`. To control the formatting of dates, times and durations, use the same class (`DateFormat`) used above to parse your original string. It has a `format` method to convert from a DateTime to a formatted string.

Comment: Solved by using this String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss').format(dateToformat); Thank you Richard